# MethodError: objects of type Float64 are not callable

Tags: julia

I made a function to find the volume of a sphere:

```
function volume_sphere(r)
  (4/3)(round(π, sigdigits=6))(r)^3
end

julia> println(volume_sphere(5))
```

I got this error message:

> ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Float64 are not callable
>   Stacktrace:
>   [1] volume_sphere(::Int64) at C:\Users\Practice.jl:27
>   [2] top-level scope at none:0

Where is the issue coming from?

Comment: Okay, I'm using mathematical notation...

Comment: Why are you rounding pi to six digits? It seems unnecessary, and makes the code less readable. You could just write `4π/3*r^3`

Comment: Not sure... I really should take advantage of Unicode like that.

Comment: Just so you know it, the `round` function _really_ slows things down. On my computer, removing the `round` function makes the calculation 40x faster.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This problem is explained in detail [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#man-numeric-literal-coefficients).

In short you are not allowed to omit `*` in juxtaposition of two parenthesized expressions, nor when placing a variable before a parenthesized expression. Therefore this is a valid code:

```
4/3*round(π, sigdigits=6)*r^3
```

But you could write e.g. `2r+3(r^2+1)r` and it would be a valid line of code.

Comment: Julia docs link is dead. I think [this](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#man-numeric-literal-coefficients) is what it was pointing towards?

Answer (score 1):

```
function volume_sphere(r)

 (4/3)*(round(π, sigdigits=6))*(r^3)

end
```